# How do you add empty cells to GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, constraints, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to achieve this effect using GridBagLayout:

```
|-----------|
|  Button1  |
|-----------|
      |-----------|
      |  Button2  |
      |-----------|
```

I initially just placed the buttons, but GridBagLayout is ignoring the empty cells.  Now, I am trying to use Box.createHorizontalStrut(10) as spacers, but GridBagLayout is stretching the spaces to give me a 2x2 grid.  I also tried JLabels and JPanels as the spacers, but I still get a 2x2 grid. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagLayoutDemo extends JFrame
{
    // class level references
    GridBagLayout layout;   
    JButton button1, button2;

    // constructor
    public GridBagLayoutDemo()
    {
        super("GridBagLayout Demo");

        layout = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout( layout );

        // create components
        button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        button2 = new JButton("Button 2");

        // components should be resized vertically AND horizontally (BOTH) to fill given area
        int fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        // if you do not fill the area, where should the component go?
        int anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        // place components on the frame using a method
        placeComponent( button1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0.5, 0.5, fill, 0, 0, 0, 0, anchor );
        placeComponent( Box.createHorizontalStrut(5), 2, 0, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.5, fill, 0, 0, 0, 0, anchor );
        placeComponent( Box.createHorizontalStrut(5), 0, 2, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.5, fill, 0, 0, 0, 0, anchor );
        placeComponent( button2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0.5, 0.5, fill, 0, 0, 0, 0, anchor );
    }

    /// Place the component on the GridBag with appropriate parameters
    private void placeComponent( Component comp, int column, int row, int width, int height, double weightX, double weightY, 
            int fill, int marginTop, int marginLeft, int marginBottom, int marginRight, int anchor )
    {
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = column;     // column to start
        constraints.gridy = row;        // row to start
        constraints.gridwidth = width;  // number of cells wide
        constraints.gridheight = height;  // number of cells tall
        constraints.weightx = weightX;    // when size is changed, grow in x direction
        constraints.weighty = weightY;    // when size is changed, grow in y direction
        constraints.fill = fill;        // should the component fill the given area?  GridBagConstraints.NONE, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, etc
        constraints.insets = new Insets( marginTop, marginLeft, marginBottom, marginRight );
        constraints.anchor = anchor;
        layout.setConstraints(comp, constraints);
        add(comp);  // place component on the frame with these parameters
    }

    /// launches the application
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GridBagLayoutDemo app = new GridBagLayoutDemo();
        app.setSize(400, 300);
        app.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: GBC is column based Layout Manager, maybe custom TableLayout is better, espeacially simpler than GBC, even possible with SpringLayout (column and row)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GridBagLayout works off of what the first word entails; a grid.  In order to achieve the effect you desire above, you actually need a 2x3 grid:

```
        c1   | c2 |   c3
             |    |  
             v    v   
     |------------|
r1   |    B1      |  <S1>
     |------------|
---->
             |------------|
r2     <S2>  |    B2      |
             |------------|
```

A 2x1 or 2x2 grid cannot realize the desired offset effect (if you want overlap on the buttons).  We need the third column in order to get that overlapping of buttons.

In this paradigm, you have the following:

```
comp    | x    | y    | w    | h
------------------------------------
B1      | 0    | 0    | 2    | 1
S1      | 2    | 0    | 1    | 1
S2      | 0    | 1    | 1    | 1
B2      | 1    | 1    | 2    | 1
```

Basically, we're saying that B1 occupies [r1, c1-c2], S1 occupies [r1, c3], S2 occupies [r2, c1], and B2 occupies [r2, c2-c3].  Hope that is clear.

Here's a MCVE that illustrates how to achieve this.  You can apply it to your code fairly painlessly:

```
public class StaggerTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stagger Test");
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    placeComp(new JButton("1"), panel, 0, 0, 2, 1);
    placeComp(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10), panel, 2, 0, 1, 1);
    placeComp(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10), panel, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    placeComp(new JButton("2"), panel, 1, 1, 2, 1);

    frame.setContentPane(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void placeComp(Component comp, JPanel panel, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();
    cons.gridx = x;
    cons.gridy = y;
    cons.gridwidth = w;
    cons.gridheight = h;
    panel.add(comp, cons);
  }
}
```

Using insets, as mentioned in the other answer could also be applicable, depending on your use case.

One thing I would caution is that, if the layout of the panel is intended to be dynamic in nature, you might want to cascade panels and layouts within panels.  For example, to extend the given example to:

```
|-----------|
|  Button1  |
|-----------|
      |-----------|
      |  Button2  |
      |-----------|
            |-----------|
            |  Button3  |
            |-----------|
```

And etc., it becomes a little messier to tackle with a single panel (especially if needing to handle dynamically; IE: add button 4 when event X occurs).  The insets approach would manage this better; you could simply iterate the inset value.

A better approach, IMO, would instead cascade your panels so that each row is managed by its own panel (and layout manager).

```
+-------MAIN PANEL----------+
| +------c1-----R1 PANEL---+|
| ||-----------|           ||
r1||  Button1  |           ||
| ||-----------|           ||
| +------------------------+|
| +---c1--------c2-R2 PANEL+|
| |       |-----------|    ||
r2|<STRUT>|  Button1  |    ||
| |       |-----------|    ||
| +------------------------+|
|  etc...                   |
+---------------------------+
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. That is what I expected to happen.  However, when you use cons.weightx = 0.5, cons.weighty = 0.0, and GridBagConstraints.BOTH so it fills the form, the form gives a 2x2 grid instead of the 3x3 grid as expected.  It looks like I may have to use Insets or a completely different layout manager to achieve my desired goal.

Comment: @Birdman Right, this is going to devolve to a 2x2 in your example.  You are applying equal weighting to 4 different components that are arranged in a manner such that 2 columns contain units each.  This will result in c2 (in my example) collapsing entirely and getting set to 0 size.  Why are you applying weighting to your spacers?

Comment: @Birdman If you do `placeComponent( Box.createHorizontalStrut(5), 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, fill, 0, 0, 0, 0, anchor );` (and likewise for the other strut) you end up closer to your desired effect (because the opposite will occur; only components that exist in c2 are requesting extra space, so c2 will eat **ALL** of the extra space.

Comment: Also note that I'm just hypothesizing that what I said in the above is true; I'm not in an environment currently where I can run your code so I can't test it.  I did try it by modifying my test code to factor in weighting/filling and it works fine though doing what I said.  If you try that and it doesn't work just LMK what you see.

Comment: If I use 0,0 as the weightx, weighty, the buttons stay small.  I can get the user's screen resolution using Toolkit and adjust the frame size based on the resolution.  However, if I use 0,0 as the weightx,weighty, the buttons are tiny on the higher resolution screens.  Here is the result when I use 0,0 on the left and a mock-up of the goal on the right.  Thank you for your help!  http://rickbird.com/downloads/GridBagLayout_Result.jpg

Comment: Apply a weight of 0,0 to the struts **only** (still put a weight on the buttons).

Comment: Note that, if you wanted your struts to grow with your component, then another approach would be to create a glue component to specifically set the c2 weight, and then associate weights with your c1 and c3 components (that is, your struts) instead of your buttons.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198804/specify-column-parameter-of-gridbaglayout-without-component) question for more details (which I raised in response to this question).

Comment: I tried using panels, but it still did not work.  I will probably use Insets to mimic the effect that I actually want.  I appreciate all of your help and I especially appreciate you posting the additional question.  You definitely understand what I want to achieve.  I am going to mark your answer since it explains everything so well.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer.  One thing I would say is that, if your spacing is intended to grow with your window sizing, then the insets approach is likely not what you want.  In the question I posted, there is some example code that, when run, shows the spacing growing when the window resizes.  I don't know if you need that (or specifically don't want that), but there it is.  Hope you end up with a satisfactory result.  Best of luck!

Comment: Ironcache, your code in the other question works perfectly.  That is what I wanted to achieve.  I am surprised that you had to create a third row with glue in the middle cell to make it work.  Whatever it takes though!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You can achieve this by using GridBagConstraints.INSETS. In your code i see you are always passing 0 to your **placeComponent** method, you just need to specify a different value.
HorizontalStruct or other components are not needed.

For example, in your code, if you use:

```
placeComponent( button1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0.5, 0.5, fill, 10, 10, 10, 10, anchor);
placeComponent( button2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0.5, 0.5, fill, 50, 100, 10, 10, anchor);
```

you will obtain:

[image]

Please note that, since you are using GridBagLayout as your content pane layout, buttons get expanded by your window size.

If you don't want your button2 to be smaller than button1, you can avoid this by using GridBagConstraints.NONE as fill parameter.

**EDIT**

I edited my answer based on your comment below.

For sure it is possible to avoid the use of GridBagLayout.NONE.

It all depends on what you want to achieve.
So, you want your buttons to have the same size, and their size to grow when you resize your window. This is ok.
But how should your button2 be "shifted" on the right of button1? By a specified number of pixels?

If so, let's say that button2 should be shifted on the right by 100 pixels, relative to button1.
This can be easily accomplished by setting your second button left insets to 100, and your first button right insets to 100 (to mantain the same size).

If in your code you replace those four lines :

```
placeComponent( button1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0.5, 0.5, fill, 0, 0, 0, 0, anchor );
placeComponent( Box.createHorizontalStrut(5), 2, 0, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.5, fill, 0, 0, 0, 0, anchor );
placeComponent( Box.createHorizontalStrut(5), 0, 2, 1, 2, 0.5, 0.5, fill, 0, 0, 0, 0, anchor );
placeComponent( button2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0.5, 0.5, fill, 0, 0, 0, 0, anchor );
```

With :

```
placeComponent( button1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0.5, 0.5, fill, 0, 0, 0, 100, anchor );
placeComponent( button2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0.5, 0.5, fill, 50, 100, 0, 0, anchor );
```

You will have this result:

[image]

And this will be your resized window:

[image]

If this is not what you would like to achieve, you'd better provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of your desired GUI at minimum size, and with more width and height.

Hope this helps !

Comment: is there any way to get around this issue without using GridBagConstraints.NONE?  I want to use GridBagConstraints.BOTH so the button grow in size as the frame grows in size.  For example, if someone uses a monitor with 1280x800 resolution, they will get a different experience than someone who uses a monitor with 2560x1600 resolution.  I can resize the frame based on the resolution using Toolkit, but NONE will keep everything very small.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Birdman I've edited my answer based on your comment. If this is not what you wanted, please provide more details.

Comment: Ansharja, thank you for your help.  It looks like I will need to use Insets to mimic the effect that I want.  Thank you.